# Previous and Next exclude the amount of pages shown

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I m using wordpress.
I want split articles into parts so I use the Page Break option. But it shows the page pagination! I want just display Prev and Nex butons.
this the code of the called funtion

```
function mts_wp_link_pages_args( $args ) {
global $page, $numpages, $more, $pagenow;
if ( !$args['next_or_number'] == 'next_and_number' )
    return $args; 
$args['next_or_number'] = 'number'; 
if ( !$more )
    return $args; 
if( $page-1 ) 
    $args['before'] .= _wp_link_page( $page-1 )
    . $args['link_before']. $args['previouspagelink'] . $args['link_after'] . '</a>'
;
if ( $page<$numpages ) 

    $args['after'] = _wp_link_page( $page+1 )
    . $args['link_before'] . $args['nextpagelink'] . $args['link_after'] . '</a>'
    . $args['after']
;
return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_link_pages_args', 'mts_wp_link_pages_args' );
```

this funtion is called like that:

```
 <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<div class="pagination">', 'after' => '</div>', 'link_before'  => '<span class="current"><span class="currenttext">', 'link_after' => '</span></span>', 'next_or_number' => 'next_and_number', 'nextpagelink' => __('Next','mythemeshop'), 'previouspagelink' => __('Previous','mythemeshop'), 'pagelink' => '%','echo' => 1 )); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `next_posts_link` and `previous_posts_link` which don't output page numbers just links to the next page of posts.

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="current"><span class="currenttext"><?php next_posts_link(esc_html__('Next','mythemeshop')); ?><</span></span>
    <span class="current"><span class="currenttext"><?php previous_posts_link(esc_html__('Previous', 'mythemeshop')); ?></span></span>
</div>
```